# Error when I passed on values on function

Tags: php, postgresql

Sorry about the last post I had. Here's my revision, please help me.

```
<?php
//connect database

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user where user_id = 8320 AND password = 'admin' ";
$query = pg_query($sql);
var_dump($row = pg_fetch_array($query)); //dumps correctly.

?>
```

BUT THE PROBLEM IS THIS..when I try to make it as a function LIKE:

```
function check($user_id, $password)
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user where user_id = $user_id AND password = '$password' ";
$query = pg_query($sql);
$row = pg_fetch_array($query);
return $row;
}
```

AND CALL IT HERE:

```
var_dump($data = check(8320, 'admin')); DUMPS NULL;
```

How come it ended up like this?

Comment: You are dumping an equation, not the return of the function.  First set the variable `$data` to equal the return of the function, and then dump the variable..or just dump the function like `var_dump(check(8320, 'admin'));`

Comment: yes.. I already did that.. still output NULL though

Comment: test $query after the pg_query call ... I think you have no results or a bad query

Comment: did u include the function or is the function is the same page?

Comment: @Orangepill, I dump $result and the output is this resource(3) of type (pgsql result)

Comment: @kevin, the function is in the same page. how come when I not use a function it will work properly?

Comment: echo $sql in your function... just to make sure... this should be working

Comment: do this at the end of the function before returning `$row`. `echo pg_fetch_array($query);` and `echo $row;`

Comment: sorry for offtopic, your code is SQL injection vulnerable! please, read some about this significant security issue - sanitize password by pg_escape_string http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

Its returning `NULL` because there is an error with your SQL query, and no results are being returned. You should do some error checking in your function, try this version:

```
function check($user_id, $password)
{
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=test");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user where user_id = $1 AND password = $2 ";
    $result = pg_query_params($dbconn, $sql, array($user_id,$password));
    $row = pg_fetch_array($result);
    if (!$row) {
       echo pg_last_error($dbconn);
    } else {
       return $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah..I'm wondering what is the error on my query when the data I passed exists in the database.

Comment: You should simply ask the database server what is the error instead of wondering about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It should work fine for you.

```
$data = check(8320, 'admin');
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: var_dump $row inside the check function and see whether you get the correct results. if the it's something wrong with your query.

Comment: I dump $row inside the function and dit dumps bool(false). why what is wrong with the query?

Comment: hope above answers has fixed the issue

Comment: waaa! when I dump $row inside the function, it has all the values I  want.. But when I dump $data it dumps null? why?

Comment: @Dasun It doesn't make any difference. `var_dump(check(8320, 'admin'))` does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your PostgreSQL resource is missing inside the function. You have two options.

1. Declare the connection resource inside the function using `global`.
2. Establish the connection inside the function.

This is the first option:

```
$conn = pg_connect('host','user','pass','db');

function check($user_id, $password)
{
   global $conn;
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM user where user_id = $user_id AND password = '$password' ";
   $query = pg_query($conn, $sql);
   $row = pg_fetch_array($query);
   return $row;
}
```

And this is the second option:

```
function check($user_id, $password)
{
   $conn = pg_connect('host','user','pass','db');
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM user where user_id = $user_id AND password = '$password' ";
   $query = pg_query($conn, $sql);
   $row = pg_fetch_array($query);
   return $row;
}
```

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php), You may omit connection resource, but it is not recommended, since it can be the cause of hard to find bugs in scripts.

Comment: I tried declaring it inside the function. still not the output I want. When I dump inside the function, it dumps bool(false) and when i dump outside the funciton it dumps null

Comment: Debugging time. Try using this code: `var_dump($sql)` after the `$sql` line. Let us know the result.

Comment: When I dump $sql it outputs string(59) "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 8320 AND password = '' "

Comment: Well, well, well, no wonder. Even your query is correct, it returns nothing since the `password` is empty. Based on the sample query on your question, the value in the `password` should be `admin`. One last thing, do `var_dump` the `$password` and let us know the result.

Comment: My fault. typo error. I dump all variables inside the function and got the results i wanted. but howcome when I dump $data it still dumps null? I cant use $data because it is null

Comment: Okay, do `var_dump` the `$row` inside the function before the `return $row`. Let us know the result.

Comment: it returns exactly as I wanted it to be BUT WHEN I call it using $data, IT DUMPS NULL..cant get in touch with this! help